# Issues when converting xml message to json

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have an xml like this.

```
<jsonObject>
    <NotANumber>1234</NotANumber>
    <emptyString/>
    <boolValue>true</boolValue>
    <textMessage>hello</textMessage>
</jsonObject>
```

I want to convert this to a json.

So, I used below synapse config.

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
<jsontransform>
    <property name="synapse.commons.enableXmlNullForEmptyElement" value = "true"/>
    <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive" value = "false"/>
</jsontransform>
```

This is my response.

```
{
    "NotANumber": "1234",
    "emptyString": null,
    "boolValue": "true",
    "textMessage": "hello"
}
```

Here, "NotANumber" is not a number but a string. "boolValue" is a boolean but not a string. But My response gives "boolValue" as a string.

This is my expected message.

```
{
    "NotANumber": "1234",
    "emptyString": null,
    "boolValue": true,
    "textMessage": "hello"
}
```

How can I get this response?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer

```
    <jsontransform>
        <property name="synapse.commons.enableXmlNullForEmptyElement" value="true"/>
        <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.disableAutoPrimitive.regex" value ="^[1-9]*$"/>
     </jsontransform>
```

This config works for me. I got the response as expected.